# Can the following series giving euler totient times the divisor sigma be written without the cardinality of this set?

Tags: number-theory

Let $$\sigma(n)=\sum_{d|n} d $$

and

$$\phi(n)= n \prod_{p|n} \left( 1-\frac {1} {p} \right) $$

Then is there a way to eliminate the set from the following statement,

$$\phi(n) \sigma(n) =n \sum_{d|n} \frac {\phi(d) | \{  m | gcd(m,n)=1 \space and \space  d | m-1 \} | } d$$

without the constraint that n is squarefree such as the following which can easily be derived from the multiplicity of the euler totient function $$\phi(n)$$ between two coprime integers and the definition of $$\sigma(n)$$

$$ \phi(n) \sigma(n) = \sum_{d|n} d \phi(d) \phi \left( \frac {n} {d} \right) $$

The original equation comes from the following:

$$\phi(n) \sigma(n) = \sum gcd(k_1-1, k_2, n)$$
where the sum is over the integers such that k_1 and k_2 are on the interval [1, n] and k_1 and n are coprime. This is a result from a generalized form of Menon's identity.

It follows, then, that

$$\phi(n) \sigma(n) = \sum \phi(t) $$
where this sum is over the integers such that k_1 and k_2 are on the interval [1, n] and k_1 and n are coprime and t divides k_1-1 and t divides k_2 and t divides n

The original equation follows immediately from this.